# Heroku deployment from travis for Meteor App

Tags: javascript, meteor, heroku, travis-ci

I'm trying to deploy to Heroku my out of the box meteor application using Travis-CI. Everything goes perfect, no error in the logs, so I try to go to my app link but I get this message:

```
Application error           
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Here is the .travis.yml file

```
sudo: required
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "stable"
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key:
    secure: "mysecretapikey"
  app:
    master: agile
```

And here the log generated from heroku

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version (latest stable) via semver.io...
       Downloading and installing node 5.11.1...
       Using default npm version: 3.8.6
-----> Restoring cache
       Skipping cache restore (new runtime signature)
-----> Building dependencies
       Pruning any extraneous modules
       Installing node modules (package.json)
       agile@ /tmp/build_ea656fe1ea6609f45441b9fe1ead456609
       └─┬ meteor-node-stubs@0.2.3
       ├── assert@1.3.0
       ├─┬ browserify-zlib@0.1.4
       │ └── pako@0.2.8
       ├─┬ buffer@4.5.1
       │ ├── base64-js@1.1.2
       │ ├── ieee754@1.1.6
       │ └── isarray@1.0.0
       ├─┬ console-browserify@1.1.0
       │ └── date-now@0.1.4
       ├── constants-browserify@1.0.0
       ├─┬ crypto-browserify@3.11.0
       │ ├─┬ browserify-cipher@1.0.0
       │ │ ├─┬ browserify-aes@1.0.6
       │ │ │ ├── buffer-xor@1.0.3
       │ │ │ └── cipher-base@1.0.2
       │ │ ├─┬ browserify-des@1.0.0
       │ │ │ ├── cipher-base@1.0.2
       │ │ │ └─┬ des.js@1.0.0
       │ │ │   └── minimalistic-assert@1.0.0
       │ │ └── evp_bytestokey@1.0.0
       │ ├─┬ browserify-sign@4.0.0
       │ │ ├── bn.js@4.11.1
       │ │ ├── browserify-rsa@4.0.1
       │ │ ├─┬ elliptic@6.2.3
       │ │ │ ├── brorand@1.0.5
       │ │ │ └── hash.js@1.0.3
       │ │ └─┬ parse-asn1@5.0.0
       │ │   ├─┬ asn1.js@4.5.2
       │ │   │ └── minimalistic-assert@1.0.0
       │ │   ├─┬ browserify-aes@1.0.6
       │ │   │ ├── buffer-xor@1.0.3
       │ │   │ └── cipher-base@1.0.2
       │ │   └── evp_bytestokey@1.0.0
       │ ├─┬ create-ecdh@4.0.0
       │ │ ├── bn.js@4.11.1
       │ │ └─┬ elliptic@6.2.3
       │ │   ├── brorand@1.0.5
       │ │   └── hash.js@1.0.3
       │ ├─┬ create-hash@1.1.2
       │ │ ├── cipher-base@1.0.2
       │ │ ├── ripemd160@1.0.1
       │ │ └── sha.js@2.4.5
       │ ├── create-hmac@1.1.4
       │ ├─┬ diffie-hellman@5.0.2
       │ │ ├── bn.js@4.11.1
       │ │ └─┬ miller-rabin@4.0.0
       │ │   └── brorand@1.0.5
       │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
       │ ├── pbkdf2@3.0.4
       │ ├─┬ public-encrypt@4.0.0
       │ │ ├── bn.js@4.11.1
       │ │ ├── browserify-rsa@4.0.1
       │ │ └─┬ parse-asn1@5.0.0
       │ │   ├─┬ asn1.js@4.5.2
       │ │   │ └── minimalistic-assert@1.0.0
       │ │   ├─┬ browserify-aes@1.0.6
       │ │   │ ├── buffer-xor@1.0.3
       │ │   │ └── cipher-base@1.0.2
       │ │   └── evp_bytestokey@1.0.0
       │ └── randombytes@2.0.3
       ├── domain-browser@1.1.7
       ├── events@1.1.0
       ├─┬ http-browserify@1.7.0
       │ ├── Base64@0.2.1
       │ └── inherits@2.0.1
       ├── https-browserify@0.0.1
       ├── os-browserify@0.2.1
       ├── path-browserify@0.0.0
       ├── process@0.11.2
       ├── punycode@1.4.1
       ├── querystring-es3@0.2.1
       ├─┬ readable-stream@2.0.6
       │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.2
       │ ├── inherits@2.0.1
       │ ├── isarray@1.0.0
       │ ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.6
       │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2
       ├─┬ stream-browserify@2.0.1
       │ └── inherits@2.0.1
       ├── string_decoder@0.10.31
       ├── timers-browserify@1.4.2
       ├── tty-browserify@0.0.0
       ├─┬ url@0.11.0
       │ ├── punycode@1.3.2
       │ └── querystring@0.2.0
       ├─┬ util@0.10.3
       │ └── inherits@2.0.1
       └─┬ vm-browserify@0.0.4
       └── indexof@0.0.1

-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
       └── meteor-node-stubs@0.2.3

-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 13.1M
-----> Launching...
       Released v3
```

As said before, it's an out-of-the-box app so there is no database, nothing that could be causing permission troubles on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, I needed to use buildpack with one of the availables for meteor in order for the app to start. I went to the command line and run heroic logs and saw the errors. I add my new .travis.yml file just in case someone steps into the same error as me:

```
sudo: required
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "stable"
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  buildpack: https://github.com/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor.git
  api_key:
    secure: "mysecretapikey"
  app:
    master: agile
```